# Is it possible to populate 2 jqGrids from a single ajax call at once?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an ASP.NET-MVC site with a webpage with 2 jqGrid's on it.  They each have their own "URL" property listed so they both call seperate ajax calls.

I want to see if its possible to merge this into a single json call that returns the json for both grids at once (instead of 2 seperate calls)

so instead of this in my controller for each method

```
        return Json(new
        {
            Page = 1,
            Records =  GetData().Count,
            Rows = GetData(),
            Total = 1
        });
```

i wanted to see if you could return both on one call:

```
   var grid1Data = (new
        {
            Page = 1,
            Records =  GetData().Count,
            Rows = GetData(),
            Total = 1
        });

   var grid2Data = (new
        {
            Page = 1,
            Records =  GetOtherData().Count,
            Rows = GetOtherData(),
            Total = 1
        });

      return Json(new
        {
                Grid1 = grid1Data, Grid2 = grid2Data
        });
```

but i can't figure out how this would work on the javascript side as right now my code looks like this (seperate ajax calls):

```
$("#myGrid1").jqGrid({
    mtype: "POST",
    url: "/GetGrid1Data",
    datatype: "json",

$("#myGrid2").jqGrid({
    mtype: "POST",
    url: "/GetGrid2Data",
    datatype: "json",
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first look the filling of two grids per one Ajax call looks attractive. The problem is that it can have some advantages only if you use `loadonce: true` options for at least in one from the grids. Only in the case you can make one Ajax call and fill another grid (which has `loadonce: true` options). The reason is simple. If you have both grids without `loadonce: true` options then the user can sort the data by clicking on the column header, click on the "Next" page of set the filter *in one grid*. In the case the data from *the grid only* needed be reloaded from the server. I see no sense to load the data for both grids in the case.

If you use `loadonce: true` options for at least in one from the grids then you can just change two options `datatype: 'json', loadonce: true` in the grid to one option `datatype: 'local'`. You can fill the grid during filling of the first grid. You can set `data` parameter for the second grid and call `roloadGrid`.

For example in the fisrt grid you can use

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "Grid1.Rows",
    page: "Grid1.Page",
    total: "Grid1.Total",
    records: "Grid1.Records"
}
```

So the grid will be loaded from the `Grid1` part of the server response. Additionally you can see `Grid2` property in the `data` parameter of `loadComplete` or `beforeProcessing` callbacks, set the `data` option of the second grid using `setGridParam` and then to trigger `"reloadGrid"` event on the grid. In the case the second grid should be created with `datatype: "local"` and the options `mtype`, `url` and `loadonce` you can remove from list of the options of the second grid.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you want this to improve performance. Well as per my knowledge jqgrid uses their own ajax calls to populate the table data.this is one cleaner way to solve grid issue but if performance is the cause which is prohibiting this solution then you can try this startegy:

```
$("#test").jqGrid({

        datatype: 'clientSide',//most important
        colNames:['xx','yy'],
        colModel :[ 
                   {name:'sdsd', index:'termId',}, 
                   {name:'version', index:'version'}, 

                   ],
                   pager: '#testpager',
                   rowNum:10,
                   rowList:[10,20,30],

                   shrinkToFit:true,
                   autowidth:true
});//grid initialised.

 $("#test2").jqGrid({

            datatype: 'clientSide',//most important
            colNames:['xx','yy'],
            colModel :[ 
                       {name:'sdsd', index:'termId',}, 
                       {name:'version', index:'version'}, 

                       ],
                       pager: '#testpager',
                       rowNum:10,
                       rowList:[10,20,30],

                       shrinkToFit:true,
                       autowidth:true
    });//grid 2 initialised.
```

//JSP------------

```
       <div id="tablecontainer" >
         <table id="test"><tr><td/></tr></table>
       <div id="testpager"></div>
</div>

  <div id="tablecontainer2" >
             <table id="test2"><tr><td/></tr></table>
           <div id="testpager2"></div>
    </div>
```

//--------

after button click fire ajax..

inside controller prepare json response as

```
   { "test":{//list of json row data},
       "test2" :{//list of json row data}}
```

//Now when ajax is successfull you will get data

add it into table using

```
  resposeSuccess(data){
            //loop through each row data and add it into respective table using
    $.each(data,function(tableId,tableJson){
       for(j=0;j<tableJson.length;tableJson++)
         $("#"+tableId).addRowData(""+j, tableJson[j]);
});


    }
```

In short instead of jqgrid,you have to take care of addition of data individually into the respective table.

Comment: Please never fill grid with respect of `addRowData` - it is the most slow way to fill the grid. Moreover in the way you fill *all data in one page*. Instead of that one should *create* the grid using `data` parameter. Additionally one should use `gridview: true` option. In the case the grid body will be filled in one operation which improve essentially performance for long grids. Another problem in your code you use `addRowData(""+j, ...`. Such call for *two grids* will produce **id duplicates** which is an error.

Comment: @Oleg.I am using addRowData..I havent noticed any performance issue as of now...normally when server side performance is more important these steps needs to be taken..2nd thing why duplicate id? each grid row will have id range from 0-pagesize..which is normally in the case of default ajax as well..Though The code I posted is just a sample..dont compare it to be tested from all side..but provide one solution path..which is free from major defects..

Comment: If you would add 100 or 1000 rows with 10 columns for example using `data` and `gridview: true` options the grid will be filled quickly. The `addRowData` will be *very* slowly. About duplicate ids: if one fill grid per Ajax the data contains `id` for every row. The values for `id` in both grids should be *different*. You use `""+j` in your code. So "0","1","2", ... will be used as the rowids. If you would use the method twice (for both grids) you will have "0","1","2", ..., in **both** grids. So if you select first row on the second grid the first row on the first grid can be selected instead.

Comment: @Oleg Not aggred yet again..we are populated 20,000 row using addRowData..getting filled in 3 sec. approx.(including server side response)..in two grid..(means 40,000 row hope this much speed is good enough..if not then with data option it might get few milli sec less..so what is the big deal)..for 2nd point we select row data using $("gridId").getRowData(1); //since gridId is unique why will I get problem mentioned by you..moreover code which I posted is tested and working..I dont think there is much left on this topic